# function in setTimeout() with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to use `setTimeout()` in a backbone model. The next code works:
`setTimeout(this.ajaxRequest,4000)` 
but not the next:
`setTimeout(function(){ 
     this.ajaxRequest;
},4000);`

Neither using `_.bind(this.ajaxRequest, this);` (Underscore.js) or

`timeoutFunction: function(){
    this.ajaxRequest;
},` with
`setTimeout(this.timeoutFunction,4000);`

setTimeout function is called when the AJAX response is done (`success:`) and `_.bindAll(this);` is executed in `initialize:`

Comment: Could we get a larger snippet of code, rather than a bunch of little snippets with no context?

Answer (score 4):

You aren't calling the functions in the setTimeout(function) calls.  For the first, you are passing a reference to a function which setTimeout is calling, the second instance you are passing a function and that function is doing nothing (nothing substantial).  That function needs to call the function `this.ajaxRequest()`

```
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function(){ _this.ajaxRequest(); },4000);
```

Comment: You're right in part. `this.ajaxRequest();`works in `timeoutFunction`but not in `setTimeout`called

Comment: Good call, yeah, this is not valid, I'm updating my code above.

Comment: I'd recommend against use `self` as the name for this sort of thing due to the existence of [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.self), if you forget the `var self = this;` then you'll be scratching your head for hours wonder WTF is going on (yes, I had to learn this the hard way). I've been using `var _this = this;`.